# How to make CORS request to google analytics super proxy deployed in app engine?

Tags: ajax, google-app-engine, google-analytics, cors

I have set up google analytics super proxy to create some public queries on my google analytics data. I have followed the instructions given in the below link to setup a analytics super proxy in app engine: https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/google-analytics-super-proxy

I have also created a public query which I have tested with a REST client (postman). I need to use this request in a web page that I'm creating. I understand that this would be a CORS request, because of which I'm not able to make a regular AJAX call. I'm not sure if the super proxy is programmed to handling CORS. How do I fire a CORS request to the super proxy deployed in app engine? Should I go with JSONP? Any sample code would be highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Anand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured it out. I had to change the response creation in analytics super proxy to include the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header:

self.response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'

Answer (score 1):

To be exact, here is the [github commit](https://github.com/erajasekar/google-analytics-super-proxy/commit/26a0fb907c268ccd70b5b16bcfdb1e610a794fee?diff=unified) showing the actual change to make to allow cross domain access for google super proxy.